# Chrome Extension Request Local Storage QuotaExceededError

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a chrome extension that can be used as a memo.

I searched the Internet and found chrome.storage APIs might be useful in my case.

However, I always encountered a "QuotaExceededError" when I request storage locally.

Here is my javascript code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    openLocalFileSystem(true);
}
function openLocalFileSystem(isReadMode) {
    navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1024 * 1024 * 10, function(grantBytes) {
        window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, grantBytes,
        function(fs) {
            console.log(grantBytes); // ALWAYS 0! WHY???
            onFileSystemOpened(fs, isReadMode);
        },
        function(e) {
            console.log("Couldn't request file system!");
        });
    });
}
```

Can someone help me out here? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

The [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage) is specific to Chrome Apps and separate from [LocalFileSystem Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem).

In order to use `requestQuota` from a Chrome App you should add the [`unlimitedStorage`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions) permission in your `manifest.json` file.

Comment: I requested permissions in my json file:   "permissions" : ["syncFileSystem", "unlimitedStorage"]. But still not working

Comment: Ive used unlimitedStorage with storage/localStorage fine but maybe it doesnt apply to filesystem storage?